# form.is_valid() returns false

Tags: django, django-views

I have this piece of code from my view. I can't figure out why the is_valid() returns false and hence no httpresponse is returned.

```
class PostTweet(View):
    """Tweet Post form available on page /user/<username> URL"""
    def post(self, request, username):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TweetForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                tweet = Tweet(text=form.cleaned_data['text'],
                user=user,country=form.cleaned_data['country'])
                tweet.save()
                words = form.cleaned_data['text'].split(" ")
                for word in words:
                    if word[0] == "#":
                        hashtag = HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=word[1:])
                        hashtag.tweet.add(tweet)
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/'+user)
```

Comment: Try `else: return HttpResponse(str(form.errors))` and you should see.

Comment: I just did and this is what it returned: country
                                                             This field is required. I am still not sure what to do as i am totally new to programming. I didn

Comment: So there you are. Your form requires a 'country' field, but there wasn't any in request.POST (or it was empty).

Comment: but the country field is a hidden element. How do i proceed

Comment: It apparently doesn't have a value. Open the Developer Tools in your browser, check the hidden input to see if it has the value you expect. Also post the form and see what the actual content of the request was.

Comment: <input id="id_country" name="country" type="hidden"> ==$0. I saw this. Truth is i dont realy know what to expect. I am only following examples from a django tutorial.

Comment: Which tutorial is it?

Comment: show how you generate your form

Comment: Add a `value` to your hidden country input.